# Adaptive Layout of Master/Detail View in Windows 10 UWP

Tags: c#, mvvm, caliburn.micro, master-detail, windows-10-universal

I looked around for several days now to find an example on how to create a master/detail view for a Windows 10 UWP app which targets a Windows tablet as well as a Windows phone. The current view already contains a SplitView, which displays the menu on the left hand side. I would like to show the master/detail in the detail view of that SplitView so that on the left hand side there is a ListView/ListBox with all selectable items and a detail view with the details of the currently selected item.

Is there a best practice? I'm using Caliburn Micro for my MVVM pattern.

Comment: the [Template10](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10) is a good place to start and works well with MVVM.

Answer (score 0):

Template 10 is a complete package but its done almost entirely with the built-ins that Jerry and Co. have come up with over the last few months putting it together.  They do have an example of MVVMLight usage with T10.  But I understand the draw of using CM.

CM is just now getting to the point where Master/Detail with UWP/ SplitView is possible with some of the bugs that came up during the release to 3.0.x sooner or later.

There are some gotchas just keep an eye on the examples.  I will probably be posting a PR for a Master/Detail shortly but I have a project to complete first.

CM with Template 10, there is a huge amount of overlap that would need to be combed over before the would work nicely between each other.  Would nice to see it; unfortunately it would be a massive undertaking to get the overlap gap closed.